# Fabric digits login with phone number button is not appearing in the relevant UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swift2

Hi I'm new to swift and currently I'm working on a project which was done in swift 2.3 for both iPad and iPhone. I did everything as it is in the documentation but the pink color login with phone number button is not appearing in my screen for some reason. The code is bellow.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftSpinner
import Crashlytics
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import DigitsKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var  phoneNum : String?
    let movement: CGFloat = 20.0
    var phoneHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    var appURLs = AppURLs.sharedInstance
    var loadingView: UIView!
    var Id: Int!
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBAction func signUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyboard = switchStoryboards()
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignUpViewController")
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        configureLoadingView()
        phoneHeight = self.view.frame.height
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
        self.username.delegate = self
        self.password.delegate = self
        self.slideMenuController()?.removeLeftGestures()
        let usernameImageView = UIImageView()
        if isIphone() {
            usernameImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 36, height: 20)
        } else {
            usernameImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 54, height: 30)
        }
        usernameImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Username")
        view.addSubview(usernameImageView)
        username.leftView = usernameImageView
        username.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

        let passwordImageView = UIImageView()
        if isIphone() {
            passwordImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 36, height: 20)
        } else {
            passwordImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 54, height: 30)
        }
        passwordImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Password")
        view.addSubview(passwordImageView)
        password.leftView = passwordImageView
        password.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

        print("Login view did load loaded")

        let authButton = DGTAuthenticateButton(authenticationCompletion: { (session, error) in
            if (session != nil) {
                // TODO: associate the session userID with your user model
                let message = "Phone number: \(session!.phoneNumber)"
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "You are logged in!", message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: .None))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: .None)
            } else {
                NSLog("Authentication error: %@", error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        authButton?.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(authButton!)


    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
    }

    func configureLoadingView() {
        loadingView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height))
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let _ = touches.first {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent:event)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField.tag == 1 {
            textField.superview?.viewWithTag(2)?.becomeFirstResponder()

        } else {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        if phoneHeight < 500.0 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, -self.movement)
            })
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        if phoneHeight < 500.0 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, self.movement)
            })
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func loginAlerts(messages: String) {
        self.activity.stopAnimating()
        SwiftSpinner.show("Sign in Failed!", animated: false).addTapHandler({
            SwiftSpinner.hide()
            }, subtitle: messages)
    }
    func switchStoryboards() -> UIStoryboard {
        switch UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom {
        case .Phone:
            // It's an iPhone
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        case .Pad:
            return UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardiPad", bundle: nil)
            // It's an iPad
        case .Unspecified:
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            // Uh, oh! What could it be?
        default:
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        }
    }

    func isIphone() -> Bool {
        switch UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom {
        case .Phone:
            // It's an iPhone
            return true
        case .Pad:
            return false
            // It's an iPad
        case .Unspecified:
            return true
            // Uh, oh! What could it be?
        default:
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can using "Debug View Hierarchy" function in xcode to  find the control's frame

Comment: im sorry im new to swift. how do you do it exactly

Comment: ok, try another way ! 1. try to print the control frame  2. bring the control to front of the superview

Comment: That didnt work